# How to edit elements in a collection from another window or Dialog

Tags: wpf, collections, properties

I have a number of collection bound to the application main window controls shown in a 
simplified form below. There are a number of other elements in the view model
(Ommited for Clarity) which all update and work as expected.

I require to edit a collection's element in another window, with the edited data back in the origonal collection.

```
/// Example of the Collection and Properties

ObservableCollection<MyData> _MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();

public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyCollection { get { return _MyCollection; } }


public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool cb_checked;

    public string Param1  { get; set; }
    public string Param2  { get; set; }
    public bool   myCheck
    {
        get { return cb_checked; }
        set
        {
            if (cb_checked == value) return;
                cb_checked = value;

             RaisePropertyChanged("Checked");

         }
     }
 }
```

My problem is how do I pass an item of a collection to a new window for editing.

My intal thoughts were to pass the item in the constructor of the window

```
   Dialog.Edit window = new Dialog.Edit(_MyCollection[2] );
   window.Owner = this;
   window.Show();
```

I also tried this as I have read I cant use indexed references

```
   var tmp = _MyCollection[2];
   Dialog.Edit window = new Dialog.Edit( tmp);
   window.Owner = this;
   window.Show();
```

but this does not work and I get null exceptions whe trying to access elements.

If I need to pass the complete collection this is also ok as they are all quite small i.e. < 50 items.

I must be going about this in the wrong way, could someone please explain how to do this
correctly please.

Many Thanks
Sarah

Comment: If I understand your question properly, take a look at this link; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application. From what you have tried and from the link I provided, you are along the right lines. You just need to bind the items to the context. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can I then have multiple bindings then to a single collection ?, i.e. both the main display and the user edit windows, if so would this be thread safe ?. Thanks

Comment: That example allows you to edit based on a selected item within the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the help - all working now.